# Neo4j Spring data POC for social RESTful layer

Tags: social-networking, neo4j, aspectj, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-mongodb

Starting to work on a new project... **RESTful** layer providing services for social network platform. 
**Neo4j** was my obvious choice for main data store, I had the chance to work with **Neo** before but without exploiting **Spring Data** abilities to map **POJO** to node which seems very convenient.

### Goals:

1. The layer should provide support resemble to *Facebook Graph API*, which defines for each *entity/object* related properties & connections which can be refer from the URL.
    [FB Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)
2. If possible I want to avoid transfer objects which will be serialized to/from domain entities and use my domain pojo's as the JSON's transferred to/from the client.

Examples:

- ***HTTP GET /profile/{id}/?fields=...&connections=...*** the response will be **Profile** object contains the requested in the URL.
- ***HTTP GET /profile/{id}/stories/?fields=..&connections=...&page=..&sort=...*** the response will be list of **Story** objects according to the requested.

#### Relevant Versions:

- Spring Framework *3.1.2*
- Spring Data Neo4j *2.1.0.RC3*
- Spring Data Mongodb *1.1.0.RC1*
- AspectJ *1.6.12*
- Jackson *1.8.5*

To make it simple we have ***Profile***,***Story*** nodes and ***Role*** relationship between them.

```
public abstract class GraphEntity {
@GraphId
protected Long id;
}
```

***Profile Node***

```
@NodeEntity
@Configurable
public class Profile extends GraphEntity {

// Profile fields
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

// Profile connections  
@RelatedTo(type = "FOLLOW", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
private Set<Profile> followThem;

@RelatedTo(type = "BOOKMARK", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
private Set<Story> bookmarks;

@Query("START profile=node({self}) match profile-[r:ROLE]->story where r.role = FOUNDER and story.status = PUBLIC")
private Iterable<Story> published;
}
```

***Story Node***

```
@NodeEntity
@Configurable
public class Story extends GraphEntity {

// Story fields
private String title;
private StoryStatusEnum status = StoryStatusEnum.PRIVATE;

// Story connections
@RelatedToVia(type = "ROLE", elementClass = Role.class, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

***Role Relationship***

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "ROLE")
public class Role extends GraphEntity {

@StartNode
private Profile profile;
@EndNode
private Story story;

private StoryRoleEnum role;
}
```

At first I didn't use **AspectJ** support, but I find it very useful for my use-case cause it is generating a divider between the POJO to the actual node therefore I can request easily properties/connections according to the requests and the [Domain Driven Design Approach](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/domain-driven-design-spring-aspectj.html) seems very nice.

***Question 1 - AspectJ:***

Let's say I want to define default fields for an object, these fields will be returned to the client whether if requested in the URL or not...so I have tried **@FETCH** annotation on these fields but it seems it is not working when using **AspectJ**.
At the moment I do it that way..

```
public Profile(Node n) {
    setPersistentState(n);
    this.id = getId();
    this.firstName = getFirstName();
    this.lastName = getLastName();  
}
```

Is it the right approach to achieve that? does the **@FETCH** annotation should be supported even when using **AspectJ**? 
 I will be happy to get examples/blogs talking about AspectJ + Neo4j didn't find almost anything....

***Question 2 - Pagination:***

I would like to support pagination when requesting for specific connection for example

***/profile/{id}/stories/*** , if stories related as below

```
// inside profile node
@RelatedTo(type = "BOOKMARK", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
private Set<Story> bookmarks;
```

***/profile/{id}/stories/*** ,if stories related as below

```
 // inside profile node
@Query("START profile=node({self}) match profile-[r:ROLE]->story where r.role = FOUNDER and story.status = PUBLIC")
private Iterable<Story> published;
```

Is pagination is supported out of the box with either **@Query** || **@RelatedTo** || **@RelatedToVia** using **Pageable** interface to retrieve **Page** instead of Set/List/Iterable? the limit and the sorting should be dynamic depending on the request from the client... I can achieve that using [Cypher Query DSL](https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-dsl) but prefer to use the basic.. other approaches will be accepted happily.

***Question 3 - @Query with {self}:***

Kind of silly question but I can't help it :), it seems that when using @Query inside the node entity ( using {self} parameter } the return type must be Iterable which make sense.. 
lets take the example of...

```
// inside profile node
@Query("START profile=node({self}) match profile-[r:ROLE]->story where r.role = FOUNDER and story.status = PUBLIC")
private Iterable<Story> published;
```

When published connection is requested:

```
    // retrieving the context profile
    Profile profile = profileRepo.findOne(id);
    // getting the publishe stories using AspectJ - will redirect to the backed node
    Iterable<Story> published = profile.getPublished();
    // set the result into the domain object - will throw exception of read only because the type is Iterable
    profile.setPublished(published);
```

Is there a workaround for that? which is not creating another property which will be @Transiant inside Profile..

***Question 4 - Recursive relations:***

I am having some problems with transitive / recursive relations, when assigning new Profile Role in Story the relation entity role contain **@EndNode** story , which contain **roles connection**...and one of them is the context **role** above and it is never end :)...
Is there a way to configure the spring data engine not to create these never ending relations?

***Question 5 - Transactions:***

Maybe I should have mentioned it before but I am using the REST server for the Neo4j DB, from previous reading I understand that there is not support out-of-the-box in transactions? like when using the Embedded server
I have the following code...

```
    Profile newProfile = new Profile();
    newProfile.getFollowThem().add(otherProfile);
    newProfile.getBookmarks().add(otherStory);
    newProfile.persist(); // or profileRepo.save(newProfile)
```

will this run in transaction when using REST server? there are few operations here, if one fail all fail?

***Question 6 - Mongo + Neo4j:***

I need to store data which don't have relational nature.. like Feeds, Comments , Massages.
 I thought about an integration with **MongoDB** to store these.. can I split domain pojo fields/connections to both mongo/neo4j with cross-store support? will it support AspectJ?

That is it for now.... any comments regarding any approach I presented above will be welcome.. thank you.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting to answer, by no means complete:

Perhaps upgrade to the the .RELEASE versions?

***Question 1***

If you want to serialize AspectJ entities to JSON you have to exclude the internal fields generated by the advanced mapping (see this [forum discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?118137-Unable-to-convert-NodeEntity-object-to-JSON-with-Jackson&p=388992#post388992)).

When you use the Advanced Mapping @Fetch is not necessary as the data is read-through from the database anyway.

***Question 2***

For the pagination for fields, you can try to use a cypher-query with `@Query` and `LIMIT 100 SKIP 10` as a fixed parameter. Otherwise you could employ a repository/template to actually fill a Collection in a field of your entity with the paged information.

***Question 3***

I don't think that the return-type of an `@Query` has to be an `Iterable` it should also work with other types (Collections or concrete types). What is the issue you run into?

For creating recursive relationships - try to store the relationship-objects themselves first and only then the node-entities. Or use `template.createRelationshipBetween(start, end, type, allowDuplicates)` for creating the relationships.

***Question 5***

As you are using SDN over REST it might not perform very well, as right now the underlying implementation uses the RestGraphDatabase for fine-grained operations and the advanced mapping uses very fine grained calls. Is there any reason why you don't want to use the embedded mode? Against a REST server I would most certainly use the simple-mapping and try to handle read operations mostly with cypher.

With the REST APi there is only one tx per http-call the only option of having larger transactions is to use the [rest-batch-api](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-batch-ops.html).

There is a pseudo-transaction support in the underlying [rest-graph-database](https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding#configuration-system-properties) which batches calls issued within a "transaction" to be executed in one batch-rest-request. But those calls must not rely on read-results during the tx, those will only be populated after the tx has finished. There were also some issues using this approach with SDN so I disabled it for that (it is a config-option/system-property for the rest-graphdb).

***Question 6***

Right now cross-store support for both MongoDB and Neo4j is just used against a JPA / relational store. We discussed having cross-store references between the spring-data projects once but didn't follow up on this.

Comment: Hi Michael and thank you for the quick response..... regarding question 1: I have no problems with the serialization to JSON i just want that few specific fields will load automatically. regarding question 3: I get that exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringEndResult cannot be cast to java.util.Collection... the rest of the answers are clear .. can you please refer me to a tutorial where using aspectJ + neo4j + spring data.. one last question what is the main use cases for working with the REST server? Thank you