# Spring data neo4j's advanced mapping vs simple mapping

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

I understand there are many advantages in using Spring data neo4j's advanced mapping rather than the simple mapping.

My question is **what are the cons of using advanced mapping** over the simple mapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel that there are almost no drawbacks of using the advanced mode. The only thing that's been bugging me, is the relatively poor IDE support of AspectJ. This was initially a hell to configure and get it right. Apart from that, our application is a lot faster with the advanced mapping mode so we never looked back.

Comment: Correct, In general SDN should be used against an embedded DB, and then advanced mapping is much faster as it does read-through and write-through (in transactions). So the IDE issue is the only caveat but if you abstain from using the methods like `persist` on the object they shouldn't affect you. And if you move your database interaction code all in transactional methods it gets even faster and more convenient (no dirty-management).

Comment: @MichaelHunger If we have multiple machines running the code which accesses the neo4j db, then how can we have neo4j in embedded mode?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Also, would you prefer advance mapping over simple mapping even if we have neo4j running in standalone mode?

Answer (score 1):

According to Q5 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138759/514402), simple mapping is favoured if you are talking to Neo4J via REST style while advanced mapping if you are using Neo4J embedded